# javascript onkeydown/onkeypress detect "shift + ö,ä,ü" in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, onkeydown, onkeypress

I wanted to detect ö,ä,ü via onkeydown, but in Firefox e.keyCode (or e.which) is 0 (for example in Chrome they are 192, 222 and 186).

So instead of using onkeydown, I used onkeypress for ö,ä,ü which worked fine until I wanted to detect the shift key as well. 
The Problem is, when the shift key is pressed, the onkeypress function does not get called. Only onkeydown and onkeyup get called, but I can't detect ö,ä and ü with these functions in FF.

So my question: Is there any workaround for FF?

Comment: Take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g6p5zby7/). It introduces [`KeyboardEvent.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) property, which is the current standard property to detect pressed keys.

Comment: That works, thank you so much +1